DBeaver: can't connect to mysql using localhost (not 127.0.0.1)
Trying to connect to MySQL via DBeaver with Server Host: 'localhost' in settings but getting error:
Access denied for user 'user'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)

localhost somehow changed to 127.0.0.1
Same error if trying to connect via ssh:
user@sl:~$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 support -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'user'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)

But it is ok, if using localhost:
user@sl:~$ mysql -h localhost support -p         
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.

So the question is how to force DBeaver (or driver) use not '127.0.0.1' but 'localhost'.

Hi this problem could have lots of reasons
1- because you are trying to enter to your db with normal user one time try with root user
2- when you use command: ip -br a you will see 127.0.0.1 and i know it's mean localhost but try it with your ip and don't use your localhost
3- most the time when people want to connect to their localhost they won't use -h switch this switch most the time use to people connecte to other servers
Same command,You can use these commands:
mysql -u root -h "127.0.0.1" -p

Or
mysql -u root -h "localhost" -p

Or
mysql -p

Have a great day.

Problem Statement
Similar situation here. Had a working setup:
graph LR
DBeaver -- ssh --> db_host -- localhost --> db

After some weeks of successful work, DBeaver stopped at login to database with:

Connection error
Access denied for user 'johndoe'@'127.0.0.1'

Workaround
Let's assert, that we talk about the same problem. Ssh into your database box and...
$ mysql -s -D foo -h localhost -u bar -p
Enter password: 
MariaDB [foo]> \q
$ mysql -s -D foo -h 127.0.0.1 -u bar -p
Enter password: 
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'bar'@'127.0.0.1'

Get the existing permissions for bar@localhost  (yours may vary):
MariaDB [foo]> show grants for bar@'localhost';
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for bar@localhost                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `bar`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '********' |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `foo`.* TO `bar`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION    |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)
MariaDB [foo]> show grants for bar@'127.0.0.1';
ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'bar' on host '127.0.0.1'

And clone them to bar@127.0.0.1  (according to yours):
MariaDB [foo]> grant usage on *.* to bar@'127.0.0.1' identified by password '********';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.009 sec)
MariaDB [foo]> grant all privileges on foo.* to bar@'127.0.0.1' with grant option;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.008 sec)

Check modification:
$ mysql -s -D foo -h 127.0.0.1 -u bar -p
Enter password: 
MariaDB [foo]> \q

Your beaver should be happy now. 
Limits of this solution
The error occured in a dynamic real world project with multiple people working on it. I had no ressources to investigate the real cause or change that led to the problem. This approach is a pure workaround that enabled me to continue my work. wfm. ymmv.
This workaround modifies account and grant setup of the database. Please use with greatest caution in any non-isolated environment. I never said, that this proposed workaround would be safe or secure in your setup.
See also

https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/4281

